# Pauli I in eoh procedure doesn't become a global phase gate in qiskit evolution_instruction method. Possible consequences

Tags: quantum-gate, qiskit, programming

If one has two qubits in arbitrary stats and wishes to apply a controlled version of some global phase gate $P(\varphi) = \begin{pmatrix} e^{i\varphi} & 0 \\ 0 & e^{i\varphi} \end{pmatrix}$ one should obtain:

$$
\left| \psi_0 \right\rangle \left| \psi_1 \right\rangle = \left(c_{00} \left| 0 \right\rangle + c_{01} \left| 1 \right\rangle \right)\left(c_{10} \left| 0 \right\rangle + c_{11} \left| 1 \right\rangle \right) \xrightarrow{\text{CP}
}$$

$$
\xrightarrow{\text{CP}}
c_{00} \left| 0 \right\rangle \left(c_{10} \left| 0 \right\rangle + c_{11} \left| 1 \right\rangle \right) + c_{01} \left| 1 \right\rangle  \left(c_{10} e^{i\varphi} \left| 0 \right\rangle + c_{11} e^{i\varphi} \left| 1 \right\rangle \right), 
$$

This example shows that in contrast to global phase gate $P$ which doesn't produce any measurable changes in a qubit state, the controlled version of it ($CP$) makes measurable changes in the state of a system of qubits. So it is ok if $P$ is ignored, but it is not ok if $CP$ is ignored (what is happening in the presented code).

Here is a code where I use `qiskit.aqua.operators.common.evolution_instruction` method, where because of (how I understand) ignoring the global phase gate, the $CP$ gate wasn't obtained (the `print(qc.qasm())` command shows no gate is added to the circuit):

```
import numpy as np
from qiskit import *
from qiskit.aqua.operators import WeightedPauliOperator
from qiskit.aqua.operators.common import evolution_instruction

phase = np.pi
pauli_dict = {'paulis': [{"coeff": {"imag": 0.0, "real": phase}, "label": "I"}]}
identity = WeightedPauliOperator.from_dict(pauli_dict)

pauli_list = identity.reorder_paulis()
instruction = evolution_instruction(pauli_list, evo_time=1, num_time_slices=1, controlled=True)

q = QuantumRegister(2)
qc_temp = QuantumCircuit(q)
qc_temp.append(instruction, q)
qc = qc_temp.decompose()

print(qc.qasm())
```

Possible consequences: when I tried to implement IPEA algorithm for $H = \begin{pmatrix} E_1 & 0 \\ 0 & E_2 \end{pmatrix}$ Hamiltonian I was estimating $E_2 - E_1$ instead of estimating $E_2$ eigenvalue. This problem was reported [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/9179/a-question-about-qiskits-weightedpaulioperator-evolve-method-for-ipea-iqpe-im). Problems may arise also for other quantum algos that use PEA as a subroutine (like HHL algo).

Is this a problem/bug? Are there alternatives to `qiskit evolution_instruction method` that don't ignore phase gates (or Pauli I operator)?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is not a problem/bug. In case the global phase gate $P$ is applied in non-controlled form, final matrix for two qubits ($P$ is acting on second qubit) is
\begin{equation}
I \otimes P =
\begin{pmatrix}
P & O \\
O & P \\
\end{pmatrix}
=\mathrm{e}^{i\phi}I
\end{equation}
So, $P$ acts as global phase gate and the phase $\mathrm{e}^{i\phi}$ can be ignored.

However, matrix of controlled $P$ is as follows
\begin{equation}
CP =
\begin{pmatrix}
I & O \\
O & P \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
Hence, $CP$ is no longer global phase gate but it prepares entangled state.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Martin :). My problem here is not about the uselessness of P gate and is not about the fact that CP isn't a global phase gate. You are right about CP and P, but my question is about qiskit's evolution_instruction method that doesn't create CP gate, when it should be created.

Comment: @DavitKhachatryan: Sorry, I probably did not understand your question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

What does the `print(qc.qasm())` yield for you?

Here is what I get:

```
OPENQASM 2.0;
include "qelib1.inc";
qreg q2[2];
Controlled-Evolution^1 q2[0],q2[1];
```

Comment: my output is:

OPENQASM 2.0;
include "qelib1.inc";
qreg q2[2];
barrier q2[0];

Comment: Did you do qc = qc_temp.decompose() part? It should be done how I understand before adding to the circuit in order to decompose "evolution" or "Controlled-Evolution" to qc gates

Comment: maybe the problem is in qc = qc_temp.decompose()? This decompose method is used in WeightedPauliOperator.evolve method for the same purpose (for obtaining gates from "evolutions")

Answer (score 0):

I just copied and pasted your code above, and that is the output I get from the print() statement. What version of qiskit do you have?

```
from qiskit import qiskit_version
print(qiskit_version)
```

Comment: {'qiskit-terra': '0.11.0',
 'qiskit-aer': '0.3.4',
 'qiskit-ignis': '0.2.0',
 'qiskit-ibmq-provider': '0.4.4',
 'qiskit-aqua': '0.6.1',
 'qiskit': '0.14.0'}

Comment: Also for example, when I am changing 'I' to 'Z' in pauli_dict I am obtaining gates, not "evolutions".

Comment: You might try installing the latest development code which may explain the difference between your results and mine. Here's my version:
{   'qiskit': '0.14.0',
    'qiskit-aer': '0.4.0',
    'qiskit-aqua': '0.7.0.dev0+6b00bb9',
    'qiskit-ibmq-provider': '0.4.6rc1',
    'qiskit-ignis': '0.3.0.dev0+59162f7',
    'qiskit-terra': '0.12.0.dev0+8700dd2'}

Comment: Thanks for your time Jack. I will try to work with qiskit's master branch and see the difference :)

Comment: Hi Jack, I tried to run the code with the latest development code and obtained the same thing that you have obtained with Controlled-Evolution^1. Now I am trying to understand what is Controlled-Evolution^1 and why it is not decomposed to a set of gates.

Comment: BTW after qc = qc_temp.decompose() step, for Z Pauli the Controlled-Evolution^1   is decomposed to the following set of gates 

u1(3.141592653589793) q2[0];
cx q2[1],q2[0];
u1(-3.141592653589793) q2[0];
cx q2[1],q2[0];

Comment: So the decomposition works for Z Pauli and doesn't work for I Pauli.